# Cant create composer.lock in docker container

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I've build my docker container from `php:8.1.0-fpm` image. Build is OK, no error, but when i'm running `composer install` i have this error  `file_put_contents(./composer.lock): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`
I'm sur my user have no enough right but i don't know how to fix it.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

ARG USERNAME=site
ARG USER_UID
ARG USER_GID

# Packages
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    vim \
    openssl \
    libicu-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    libc-client-dev

# OPCache + APCu
RUN docker-php-ext-configure opcache --enable-opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-install opcache

RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

# Zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

# User
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    # Add user as root
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

USER $USERNAME

# Composer
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN composer self-update

# Workdir
COPY . .
WORKDIR /var/www
CMD composer install ; php-fpm
EXPOSE 9000
```

and my docker-compose :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  php-astrobin-ws:
    container_name: php_astrobin_ws
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      args:
        USER_UID: ${SITE_UID:-1000}
        USER_GID: ${SITE_GID:-1000}
    env_file:
      - .env.local
      - .env
    volumes:
      - "./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-stack-custom.ini"
      - .:/var/www
```

Rights on directory when i'm in my container :

```bash
site@cd87de6daddf:/var/www$ ls -al /var/ | grep www
drwxr-xr-x 7 65716   513 4096 Mar 30 11:31 www
```

Source for adding user : https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-nonroot-user

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found, it vas about uid and gid.
In my example, i'm setting :

```
      args:
        USER_UID: ${SITE_UID:-1000}
        USER_GID: ${SITE_GID:-1000}
```

So my user site got 1000:1000 instead of SITE_UID and SITE_GID setted in env.local file
I've seen with :

```bash
site@cd87de6daddf:/var/www$ id -u
1000
site@cd87de6daddf:/var/www$ id -g
1000
```

or www directory is mounted with values in .env.local.

So, i've moving from env.local

```
SITE_UID=XXX
SITE_GID=YYY
```

to .env, and delete "-1000" in my docker-compose and all it's ok.
The only question is : why my docker-compose don't read .env.local variables by .env ?